# Matrix form of complex numbers

Tags: matrix, complex

Complex numbers have [matrix form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Matrix_representation_of_complex_numbers). But some 2x2 matrices while differ, represent the same complex number. To compare complex numbers one has to transform the matrices to the form

\begin{pmatrix}
  a &   -b  \\
  b & \;\; a
\end{pmatrix}.

How I transform an arbitrary 2x2 matrix representing a complex number to this form without changing its complex number value?

Comment: c = a + I b; Refine[{{Re[c], -Im[c]}, {Im[c], Re[c]}}, 
 Assumptions -> {a, b} \[Element] Reals]?

Comment: @Algohi how to transform a matrix to this form? You show how to produce a matrix given a complex number, I am looking for the opposite.

Comment: Do you mean MatrixForm?

Comment: @Algohi it only changes appearance, it does not change the matrix.

Comment: I don't really get what you want. if you are looking to get the complex number from the matrix then take the first column m[[;;,1]].{1,I}

Comment: Related [Demonstrations Project](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MatrixRepresentationOfTheMultiplicativeGroupOfComplexNumbers/)

Comment: What would be an example of two different matrices that represent the same complex number?

Comment: As far as I know the matrix above uniquely codes for the complex number a + b i. See, e.g., [this page](http://www.sosmath.com/matrix/complex/complex.html). Please give an example or reference of the contrary as Daniel asked.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries if the numbers on the main diagonal different.

Comment: If the numbers on the diagonal are different the complex number they code for is different.

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries any complex, dual and split-complex number can be presented in the form of a matrix where the numbers on the main diagonal are the same

Comment: In not talking about the numbers in one matrix diagonal, but about two different matrices. As far if I know if the diagonals differ the complex numbers differ. And you still haven't given the example we asked for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works for matrices representing ordinary complex numbers.

```
matrixToComplexNumber[{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}] := Module[{p, q, x},
  p = (a - d)^2/4 + b c;
  If[p >= 0, Return["N is not an ordinary complex number"]];
  x = (a + d)/2;
  Return[{x, Sqrt[-p]}];
  ]
```

See: [2x2 Real Matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_%C3%97_2_real_matrices)

Comment: Thanks! But why it returns for {{0,-1,1,0}} and {{0,1,-1,0}} the same result? It should be i and -i.

Comment: I am also interested in how to adapt it for dual numbers.